# How to change from a vector parametric description to a cartesian when describing a 2 dimensional flat in 5 dimensions?

Tags: linear-algebra, parametric

[image]

I'm completely stuck on how to start this question; I'm not sure If I can get one cartesian to describe this flat or if I need multiple?

Comment: this is a two-dimensional space, so you have to find $s$ and $t$ in order to obtain a system described by 3 equations .

Comment: @psidaga At the moment I have v = 1+s and w = 2+s if I add these I get s = (v+w-3)/2. Would this be one of the equations?

Answer (score 0):

We are in a $5$-dimensional vector space $V$ with two free parameters, so our vector subspace $U$ has dimension $2$.
If we now want to obtain its cartesian representation we need to find the scalar parameters $s$ and $t$ in function of the variables $v,w,x,y,z$ in order to obtain a system of three equations that describes a plane in the vector space $V$.
$$\begin{cases}
  v = 1+s \\
  w= 2+s \\
  x =3\\
  y=4+t\\
  z=5 +t
\end{cases} 
\iff
\begin{cases}
  s = v-1 \\
  w= 2+s \\
  x =3\\
  t=y-4\\
  z=5 +t
\end{cases}
\iff
\begin{cases}
  s = v-1 \\
  t= y-4 \\
  x =3\\
  z=5+y-4\\
  w=2+v-1
\end{cases}
\Longrightarrow
\pi\equiv\begin{cases}
  x-3=0 \\
  y-z+1=0 \\
  v-w+1=0
  \end{cases}$$